# Terraform: How can I reference Terraform cloud environmental variables?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform cloud. I would like to take advantage of using AWS Tags with my resources. I want to tag each resource defined in Terraform with the current GIT Branch Name. That way I can separate dev from production.

Terraform has a list of Environmental Variables that do reference the GIT Branch Name with their service in the cloud as:

```
TFC_CONFIGURATION_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH - This is the name of the branch that the associated Terraform configuration version was ingressed from (e.g. master).
```

How can I reference the *TFC_CONFIGURATION_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH* environmental variable in the following resource for an example VPC?

```
resource "aws_vpc" "example_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    product = var.product
    stage = var.TFC_CONFIGURATION_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH
  }
}
```

reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#environment-variables

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out! Wish the documentation was clearer on this with the cloud.

You will have to set a empty variable. I defined mine in variables.tf as:

```
variable "TFC_CONFIGURATION_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH" {
  type = string
  default = ""
}
```

Per the documentation I linked in question. *TFC_CONFIGURATION_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH* is injected automatically into the environmental variables with each cloud run. Defining the full name of the environmental variable as the variable worked.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "example_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    product = var.product
    stage = var.TFC_CONFIGURATION_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH
  }
}
```

Then the plan output was successful in the cloud:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_vpc.example_vpc will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_vpc" "example_vpc" {
        id                               = "vpc-0b19679e6464b8481"
      ~ tags                             = {
          ~ "stage"   = "None" -> "develop"
            # (1 unchanged element hidden)
        }
        # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Terraform Cloud serves as a remote execution environment for Terraform CLI (amongst other things) and so when you configure a workspace in Terraform Cloud many of the settings are about the context where Terraform CLI will run, and how Terraform Cloud will run it.

Part of that configuration model is the idea of environment variables, which correspond with the same environment variables you might set in your shell when running Terraform CLI locally. As with local Terraform, those environment variables are not directly usable from your configuration but are instead settings for other systems that Terraform and providers will interact with, such as the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` environment variable conventionally used by AWS software as a way to statically configure the access key identifier to use.

Terraform Cloud also allows you to set "Terraform Variables", and those correspond with [Input Variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html) in the Terraform language. These are the settings for your Terraform configuration itself, as opposed to other software it will interact with, and so you can refer to these by declaring them using `variable` blocks and then using expressions like `var.example` elsewhere in the root module. Internally, Terraform Cloud is passing the configured values to Terraform CLI by generating a file called `terraform.tfvars`, which Terraform CLI looks for as a default source of variable values.

Both of these types of variables are useful for different purposes, and so most Terraform workspaces include a mixture of environment variables for configuring external systems and "Terraform variables" for configuring the current Terraform configuration itself.

---

For the benefit of folks using Terraform CLI *outside* of Terraform Cloud, Terraform CLI actually also offers [a way to set Input Variables using environment variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#environment-variables), and technically you can do that within Terraform Cloud too because it's ultimately just running Terraform with environment variables set in the same way as you might locally. That's not the intended way to use Terraform Cloud, and so I'm mentioning it only for completeness because the terminology overlap here might be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Terraform cloud workspace variables can be set as category "terraform" or as category "env". In a remote execution setup, you are unable to reference workspace vars defined as "env" from your terraform code. Instead, those vars will be automatically injected into the execution environment. To be able to reference a workspace variable in terraform code, set the variable type to "terraform" but do not check the "HCL" tick. Defining a blank variable is still needed. Hope this helps someone! Unfortunately, the documentation is very unclear about this.

Comment: And how do i reference that variable in my script? var.myworkspacevariable?

Answer (score 0):

**Terraform Cloud: Create a workspace variable**

- key: example_variable
- value: example_value
- category: terraform

**Implementation: Configuration (.tf) file**

- Declare a blank variable
- Reference your variable

```
# Declaring a blank variable
variable "example_variable" {}

# Referencing a variable
block "name" {
input = var.example_variable
```

**Snowflake CI/CD Example**

- CI/CD pipeline for Snowflake with GitHub Actions and Terraform configured similar to [Snowflake's quick start guide](https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/devops_dcm_terraform_github/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)
- Implemented a private key instead of a user password

```
variable "snowflake_private_key" {}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    snowflake = {
      source  = "chanzuckerberg/snowflake"
      version = "0.25.17"
    }
  }

  backend "remote" {

    organization = "terraform-snowflake"

    workspaces {
      name = "gh-actions"
    }
  }
}

provider "snowflake" {
  username    = "snowflake-username"
  account     = "snowflake-account"
  region      = "snowflake-region"
  private_key = var.snowflake_private_key
  role        = "SYSADMIN"
}
```